# Python: How to use use a while loop to only print the values in the list that are divisible by a certain interger

Tags: python, list, if-statement, random, while-loop

I am trying to create a list that holds 10 random numbers in a range of 1 to 10 and use a while loop to only print the values in the list that are divisible by 3.

So far I made this code:

```
import random
list = []
randlist = random.sample(range(0, 10), 10)
list.append(randlist)
while len(list) > 0:
    if (list[0] % 3 == 0):
        print(list)
```

But I get the error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

How do I fix this code? Everything runs perfectly until the while loop.

Comment: `randlist` is a list, so `list[0]` is a list.

Comment: The structure of your `list` is `[[1, 2, 3, ...]]` -- it is a nested list. Furthermore, don't use `list` as a variable name. It is the name of a built-in function in Python which you are overwriting.

Comment: Why do you need the `list` variable? `randlist` is a list, you should loop through that.

Comment: You have an infinite loop. Nothing changes the length of the list in the loop, so it will keep printing element 0 if it's a multiple of 3.

Comment: You should also use a `for` loop, since you are iterating a known number of times (the number of elements in the list of random integers). You only use a `while` loop when the number of iterations you need to perform is unknown *a priori*.

Comment: when you call `list.append(randlist)`, you get a nested lists, if you want to display correctly your numbers, you could apply  this to iterate on `randlist`, i. e. `while len(randlist) > 0` and replace whole code by: `if (randlist[-1] % 3 == 0):  print(randlist.pop())`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to take the modulus of a list.

On line 4: `list.append(randlist)`, you are appending a list of numbers, `randList` into `list`.

This means that `list[0]` will simply return `randList`. If we want to retrieve a number from `randList`, we could do:

```
while len(list) > 0:
    if (list[0][0] % 3 == 0):
        print(list)
```

However, there is no need for `list` now since we know `randList` will store the 10 random numbers.

To find the numbers in `randList` that are divisible by 3, we can iterate through the list with a loop and use an if statement:

```
for i in randlist:
  if i % 3 == 0:
    print(i)
```

If you truly want to use a while loop, we can create a counter variable, `index`, and **while** `index < len(list)`, we can check to see if the element of `randList` at index, `index` is divisible by 3. Make sure you increment the value of `index` so we don't end up in an infinite loop!

```
index = 0
while index < len(randlist):
  if randlist[index] % 3 == 0:
    print(randlist[index])
  index += 1
```

We can also use `print(randlist)` just to make sure we iterated through the whole list and got all the multiples of 3.

I hope this helped answer your question! Please let me know if you need any further clarification or details :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with list comprehension.

```
import random

[rand for rand in random.sample(range(0, 10), 10) if rand%3==0]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have used `list` in your code. Which makes it a nested list like`[[1, 2, ..]]` .

Solution to your code is:

```
import random

randlist = random.sample(range(0, 10), 10)

length = len(randlist)
while length > 0:
    num = randlist[length-1]
    if (num % 3 == 0):
        print(num)
    length = length - 1
```

A simple solution of it to use a for loop instead of a while. You can do with for loop like

```
import random

randlist = random.sample(range(0, 10), 10)

for num in randlist:
    if (num % 3 == 0):
        print(num)
```

You don't need to reduce the `index` in for loop.

The same can be done by list comprehensive.

```
import random

randlist = random.sample(range(0, 10), 10)

moduled_list = [num for num in randlist if num%3 ==0]
print(moduled_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the *append()* method and use randlist as argument. The result is that you create a list into another list. You can verify that by printing your list and look at the result you obtain.
As the *random.sample()* method already creates the desired list you do not have to use the *append()* method here. Namely, after your list with random numbers has been created you can simply iterate over all numbers in this loop and check at each iteration if the number is divisible by three. Thus, I would recommend you to use a *for* loop instead of a *while* loop.

The following code prints all numbers of the random list that are divisible by three:

```
import random
list = random.sample(range(0, 10), 10)
for number in list:
    if (number % 3 == 0):
        print(number)
```

A second and more advanced method would be to use list comprehension:

```
import random
print([number for number in random.sample(range(0, 10), 10) if number % 3 == 0])
```